# Assign a 3D vector to a 4d vector or how to cast a cv::Vec<double, 4> to cv::Vec<double, 3> using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, casting, reinterpret-cast

Is there a better or more efficient way to cast a `cv::Vec<double, 4>`  to `cv::Vec<double, 3>`.
The example shows my current solution using `reinterpret_cast`. Where I like to point out that the vector **c** points to the same data as vector **a** but as a `cv::Vec<double,3>`.

```cpp
cv::Vec<double, 4> a(1,2,3,4);
cv::Vec<double, 3> b(5,6,7);
std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << std::endl;
cv::Vec<double, 3> &c = reinterpret_cast<cv::Vec<double, 3>&>(a);
c = b;
std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << std::endl;
```

output:

```
a: [1, 2, 3, 4], b: [5, 6, 7]
a: [5, 6, 7, 4], b: [5, 6, 7]
```

**In order to make my point clear**
In my use case, I have to operate on a huge set of `cv::Vec4d` object instances. And I would like to avoid copping data to back and forth.

Comment: By definition, anything is better than the undefined behavior of the sort the shown code is doing.

Comment: I don't know why so many people think that *casts* can be used to convert between unrelated types. They *cannot* - is the compiler supposed to just magically know how to convert one type to another and generate code to do that conversion? It *can't do that*. Casts are basically just subversions of the type system, saying to the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing, just treat this `foo` as a `bar` it'll be fine". Mostly, use of casts indicate code with bugs (like here).

Comment: `cv::Vec<double, 3> &c = reinterpret_cast<cv::Vec<double, 3>&>(a);` -- Remove the `reinterpret_cast` and figure out why the compiler will now give you an error.  The compiler will be telling you the types are not the same.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is the question, how to  solve that error.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better or more efficient way ... ?

Yes. The way you do it now has *undefined behavior*. Any way that has **defined** behavior is better.

What you've observed when compiling and running your current program is nothing you should rely on.

You'd also get exactly the same efficiency by copying directly from the source `Vec` into the destination `Vec` using the `public` member variable `_Tp val [m*n];`.

I would advice against using the constructor taking a pointer to an array without defined bounds because mistakes are just too easy to make.

```cpp
cv::Vec<double, 3> a(1,2,3);
cv::Vec<double, 4> c(a.val); // boom
```

By defining a helper function that asserts that you are staying within the defined bounds, you can do these transformations in a controlled and safe way without worrying too much.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

template<std::size_t SrcPos, std::size_t DstPos, std::size_t Len,
         class T1, int N1, class T2, int N2>
void copy_from_to(const cv::Vec<T1, N1>& src, cv::Vec<T2, N2>& dst) {
    static_assert(SrcPos + Len <= N1, "Source out of bounds");
    static_assert(DstPos + Len <= N2, "Destination out of bounds");
    std::copy_n(src.val + SrcPos, Len, dst.val + DstPos);
}
```

```cpp
int main() {
    cv::Vec<double, 4> a(1, 2, 3, 4);
    cv::Vec<double, 3> b(5, 6, 7);

    std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';

    copy_from_to<0,0,3>(b, a);

    std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: In my use case, I have to operate on a huge set of Vec4d object instances. And I would like to avoid copping data to back and forth.

Comment: @Max You are already copying. The way I propose just makes it safe. If you only need to view the array as a `double[3]`, use a `std::span`

Comment: No, I do not copy. If you look at my example you will see that, after assigning __b__ to __c__ with `c=b`the first entries on __a__ are changed.

Comment: @Max Yes, that's a _copy_ assignment. What I propose does the same amount of copying - but is defined by the standard to work.

Comment: If you'd like a non-copying alternative, I can provide a bounds-narrowing  `Vec` shell later.

Comment: This is just an example `c=b` in my showcase I am calling a function with a reference to  `cv::Vec3d` which returns a modified element.

Comment: @Max You are trying to escape the fact that you copy. The only difference is that my (or Jan's) suggestion is defined to work.

Comment: If you really want to work on a `Vec4` in functions taking a `Vec3` you can make such a wrapper that makes it defined. Your way is not.

Answer (score 1):

> ```cpp
> cv::Vec<double, 3> &c = reinterpret_cast<cv::Vec<double, 3>&>(a);
> ```

Using `c` would be undefined behavior.
`c` is an lvlaue of a type `Vec<double, 3>` which refers to an object of type `Vec<double, 4>`. Using it is UB as per [[basic.lval] p11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11). See also [What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8)

It doesn't matter that these two types are "vaguely similar", and that they both store a `double[]` of some size, although that similarity makes it "work" on your machine.

The proper way would be to create a new `cv::Vec<double, 3>`:

```cpp
cv::Vec<double, 4> a(1,2,3,4);
cv::Vec<double, 3> c(a.val);

// or as an expression:
std::cout << cv::Vec<double, 3>(a.val) << std::endl;
```

This uses the [constructor of `cv::Vec`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html#ae18d706f80604c0ff965ae3e0990133b) which takes a `const double*`.

Comment: This answer is not for I was looking for.
It makes a copy of the data. I am looking for a way to operate on the data of a as they where a Vec3d.

Comment: @Max the best you can do is just take the array from `val` and work directly with that. Note that copying the data is trivially cheap, so if you're worried about performance, don't be

Comment: I have up to 5 million entries

Comment: @Max You are copying 3 `double`s every time you do `c = b;` - Jan's suggestion takes the un out of undefined.

Comment: This is just an example `c=b` in my showcase I am calling a function with a reference to  `cv::Vec3d` which returns a modified element.

Comment: @Max you should have made it clear what you actually want to do in your question. Maybe you should write a template that works with a reference to a vector containing 3 or more elements. I don't know, because you haven't made things clear.

Comment: @Max The operator overload you claim to have is only a mirrage. You know it does not exist because it can not exist. Provide a proper representation of your code and we may provide proper ways to progress.